# Using parameters in action of UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to call a function with parameters using the action of `UITapGestureRecognizer` and I can't figure out any alternative.

This here is the gesture that is suppose to call the doubleTap function with the `indexPath` parameter.

```
var gestureDoubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTap(indexPath)")
```

This here is the function that is suppose to be called.

```
func doubleTap(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("double tap")
    NSLog("%@", indexPath.row)
}
```

How can I call the `doubleTap` function with the `indexPath` parameter?

Thank you for all suggestions.

***EDIT*** - this is my whole code, it is basically setting up the object 'name' so my second viewController can get it and use it

```
import UIKit
class viewController1: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imageArray:[String] = []
    var name : AnyObject? {
        get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue!, forKey: "name")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as myViewCell

        //adding single and double tap gestures for each cell
        /////////////////////////////
        //ISSUE IS SENDING indexPath TO doubleTap FUNC
        var gestureDoubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTap:")
        gestureDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(gestureDoubleTap)

        var gestureSingleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap")
        gestureSingleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(gestureSingleTap)

        cell.imgView.image=UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])        
        return cell
    }

    //func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    //
    //    name = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    //}

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageArray=["1.png","2.png","2.png","1.png","1.png","2.png","1.png","2.png","1.png","2.png","1.png","2.png","1.png","2.png","1.png","2.png"]

    }

    func doubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        var tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)

        var indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(tapLocation)!

        //var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        NSLog("double tap")
        NSLog("%@", indexPath)

        //NSLog("%@", cell!)
        //THIS IS THE GOAL----- set 'name' with the appropriate img      corresponding the cell
        //name = imageArray[indexPath]
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
    }

    func singleTap() {
        NSLog("single tap")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Given that you have `NSIndexPath`, I suppose you would like to retrieve the corresponding `indexPath` from the tap touch point on your `UITableView`.

`UIGestureRecognizer` has one (or no) parameter. When there is one provided, it passes itself - the `indexPath` is, however, *not* passed to the function as mentioned.

Let's say we have the following:

```
let aTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
```

and the corresponding function when the view is tapped on:

```
func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    //using sender, we can get the point in respect to the table view
    let tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)

    //using the tapLocation, we retrieve the corresponding indexPath
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(tapLocation)

    //finally, we print out the value
    print(indexPath)

    //we could even get the cell from the index, too
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello, Cell!"
 }
```

***Update:***

This serves to show how to add a gesture recognizer to the view, through which we retrieve the `indexPath` of the `cell` (`item`) that was tapped on twice.

The callback function is triggered, within which we could check whether or not the `cell` (`item`) that was tapped on is the one we are interested in.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let doubleTaps = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTapTriggered:")
    doubleTaps.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTaps)
}

func doubleTapTriggered(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    var tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(tapLocation)!

    if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    {
        if(cell.tag == 100)
        {
            print("Hello, I am cell with tag 100")
        }
        else if(cell.tag == 99)
        {
            print("Hello, I am cell with tag 99")
            //We could do something, then, with the cell that we are interested in.
            //I.e., cell.contentView.addSubview(....)
        }
    }
}
```

***Another Update:***

Since it appears that you are adding gesture recognizer that requires double taps to all cells, which tells me that you are interested in any cell that was double-tapped on; and so, we would't need any condition to check whether or not the cells are the ones we are interested in, because they all are.

And so:

```
func doubleTapTriggered(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    var tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(tapLocation)!

    name = imageArray[indexPath]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense, except I am using UICollectionView, I am guessing its the same procedure and I can get the tapLocation and indexPath of the UICollectionCell?

Comment: I can't seem to get the an integer from indexPath. when I print indexPath I get "0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}" in my console. how do i just get the 0 out of this indexPath? indexPath.row does not work, it says it is not a member of indexPath

Comment: If i add the gesture recognizer to the view than any tap or double tap will trigger the gesture, I need it so each cell has their own function when tapped or double tapped

Comment: Where would the condition be placed? in doubleTap(sender: UITapGestureGecognizer) function? Can you give me a more specefic exampl please.

Comment: I did NSLog("@", cell.tag) in the if condition and it always returns null, I am not getting an identification

Comment: Update 2 would work if indexPath would return only an integer but it returns 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

Comment: your indexPath returns just an integer? mine returns all that giberish ahaha

Comment: I just found the issue! for some reason when i NSLog("%@", indexPath.row) it returns null, but with NSLog("row is \\(indexPath.row)") it returns the correct integer! so indexPath.row was working this entire time :OOO

Answer (score 3):

The Best way to achieve what you wish is get the superview of your tap gesture, this will give you the correct indexPath. Try this:

```
   func doubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.view
        let mainCell = point?.superview
        let main = mainCell?.superview
        let cell: myViewCell = main as! myViewCell
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    }
```

You can increase or reduce the superview's depending on you hierarchy level.

Comment: Actually, this is in no way the 'best' way. Especially in consideration of the question and the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call it without using any kind of parameters in your string literal.

```
var gestureDoubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTap:")
```

The `:` tells the computer that you're using a function with a parameter, and that is created somewhere else.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: okay that makes a bit of sense to me, but then how does doubleTap func actually receive the indexPath variable?

Comment: It'll be called through your action. The function being called handles all the parameter information

Answer (score 0):

As described in apple developer documents, the action parameter should receive

> **action::-**
>   A selector that identifies the method implemented by the target to handle the gesture recognized by the receiver. The action selector must conform to the signature described in the class overview. NULL is not a valid value.

And  Valid action method signatures described in UIGestureRecognizer.h are:

> //     -(void)handleGesture;
>   //     -(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;

So basically, you will **not** be able to send anything else as the parameter except the gestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Further to `user2277872`'s response that I also found useful, and just for anyone else who may not be familiar - `IBAction` functions can *also* be connected by dragging from the xib to a *prewritten* function in the class - this is useful if **no parameters** are desired (i.e. without the `:` character that was previously mentioned).

**Example with no parameters**

```
@IBAction private func somethingTapped() {
        ...
}
```