# Swift: tap Gesture not recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am having some trouble getting my tap gesture to work when my code is separated into classes. I had this all contained in one file earlier and it worked smoothly so I assume I did something wrong in the following code:

```
placeContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = true

let showFullPlaceContainerView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(self.showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(placeContainerView)))
placeContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(showFullPlaceContainerView)
```

where the function `showFullContainerViewFunction(placeContainerView)`

```
func showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(placeContainerView: PlaceContainerView) {
    placeContainerView.animateExpandContractContainer()   
}
```

and

```
func animateExpandContractContainer() {
    print("Tap gesture working")
    if self.displayingPlaceLabel == false {
        print(self.displayingPlaceLabel)
        self.displayingPlaceLabel = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.center.x += 180
            }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.displayingPlaceLabel = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.center.x -= 180
            }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Somehow the placeContainerView is not recognising the taps and does not return any print statements when clicked.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure how, but selectors `#selector(className.methodName)` should not have any parameters. So there is something wrong with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085396/using-parameters-in-action-of-uitapgesturerecognizer-in-swift

Comment: I think your selector is wrong. It should be '#selector(Classname.showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(_:))' instead of 'Selector(self.showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(placeContainerView))'

Comment: @RJE I've replaced it as you've said and the code gives no errors but when I run it and try to tap the "placeContainerView" I get an error where the animateExpandContractContainer is called - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @impression7vx you're right. I changed my selector to match what RJE wrote in order to pass the placeContainerView

Comment: mm, I just noticed that method parameter is not a UIGestureRecognizer. Tap gesture will pass UITapGestureRecogninser (we cannot change this behavior). You have to find your 'PlaceContainerView' using the recognizer or keep a global reference. eg. 'func showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed Selector syntax as you suggested

```
let showFullPlaceContainerView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(_:)))
placeContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(showFullPlaceContainerView)
```

Your method will be like this

```
func showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let placeContainerView = recognizer.view as! PlaceContainerView
    placeContainerView.animateExpandContractContainer()   
}
```

Comment: I had to use RJE's suggestion for the selector but this worked.

Comment: Welcome mate happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you man! Could you explain how I can cast recognizer as a different class? The thought never crossed my mind. Does UITapGestureRecognizer just grab whichever object was tapped?

Comment: `recognizer.view` will give you the view object in which `gesture` is added, hope you get it it now.

Answer (score 2):

look at placeContainerView's  and  its superview    frame and userInteractionEnable.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the parameter of the expected function?

```
placeContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
let showFullPlaceContainerView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.yourFunction(_:))
placeContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(showFullPlaceContainerView)
```

Your expected function should be like this:

```
func yourFunction(tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   // Do something
}
```